# SQL Reformatting my date column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that has a date column. For example:

```
| User |    Date    |
|  1   | 05-16-2016 |
|  1   | 07-28-2016 |
| ....
```

Notice how the format of the date is month-day-year. Basically I want to reformat it so that it does: day-month-year. So the resulting table would look like:

```
| User |    Date    |
|  1   | 16-05-2016 |
|  1   | 28-07-2016 |
| ....
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: What is the locale of your computer? This is set in Windows console.

Comment: It's English (Canada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. Basically all you do is use format like this:

```
FORMAT(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

And I created a new column for the formatted date and used that column to carry out other computations

Comment: You should never handle dates as strings. No exceptions. If your other computations contain string dates, convert these to true date values.

Comment: The data type of my date is date and after format I can reconvert to date

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you need the date _value_, that's what you have. Format returns a string.

Comment: Well, like i said i needed to reformat the date value for a specific reason unrelated to the question